Hard problems with an easy-to-understand answer
I am very interested by problem in mathematics which are difficult (go at least 10 years without a resolution, say) but which have a solution that is short and elementary.
In this video Launay gave an example, namely A non-terminating game of Beggar-My-Neighbor (incorrectly claimed in Winning Ways to have been solved a long time ago).
Launay calls these problems "Pokémon problems": difficult to catch but once you catch them, they're in your pocket.
Question: What are other problems like this?

@Dattier Since it presumably fits in less than 10 lines, you should probably just give Launay's example rather than ask people to go and watch a YouTube video...

Le lien est mort : https://www.richardpmann.com/beggar-my-neighbour-records.html

I don't suppose there's a ten-line proof of PRIMES is in $P$, nor of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$, but they are both longstanding problems that were settled using mathematics at a surprisingly elementary level. One might add Mihǎilescu's proof of Catalan's conjecture.

This question has been closed as not being about research-level mathematics. I think the answers that have been posted (by me, but, still), one concerning the existence of orthogonal Latin squares, the other concerning a Diophantine equation associated to Euler, are indisputably about research-level mathematics, and that means the question is about research-level mathematics. Please vote to reopen (I have another answer I'd like to post!).

Related: Quick proofs of hard theorems.

The question, raised by Euler, as to whether fewer than $n$ $n$th powers could sum to an $n$th power, was settled considerably more than ten years later by Lander and Parkin, the justification taking only one line, at high school level,
$$
27^5+84^5+110^5+133^5=144^5
$$
see

L. J. Lander and T. R. Parkin, Counterexample to Euler’s conjecture on sums of like powers, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 72 (1966), 1079 https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3/


Your two answers concern examples (or counter-examples). And it is quite understandable why: it fits with the "NP" paradigm in computer science that there can be examples which are hard to find but which are easy to verify. Nevertheless, I wonder whether there are answers that are more traditional theorems (universally quantified statements, say).

@Sam, it did also occur to me that examples/counterexamples are the most likely results to qualify as answers to this question. After all, if a problem is open for ten or more years, and falls to a short argument of an elementary type, that argument is most likely some kind of lengthy computation with a simple verification.

For reasons I'll explain at the end, I'm not certain this one qualifies, but here goes:
In 1934, Romanoff (sometimes spelled "Romanov") proved that the integers of the form $2^k+p$ ($p$ being a prime) have positive density. He asked whether there are infinitely many odd numbers that are not of the form $2^k+p$. In 1950, Erdős was the first to give the affirmative answer to this question; in fact, he produced an arithmetic progression of odd numbers, none of them of the form $2^k+p$.
His proof, in its entirety, is this:
"Clearly every integer satisfies at least one of the following congruences: $0\bmod2$, $0\bmod3$, $1\bmod4$, $3\bmod8$, $7\bmod{12}$, $23\bmod{24}$. Therefore, if $x$ is congruent to $1\bmod2$, $1\bmod7$, $2\bmod5$, $2^3\bmod{17}$, $2^7\bmod{13}$, and $2^{23}\bmod{241}$, then for any $k$, $x-2^k$ is a multiple of (at least) one of the primes $3$, $5$, $7$, $13$, $17$, $241$."
To see how this works, say, for example, that $k\equiv3\bmod8$. Then $2^k\equiv2^3\equiv x\bmod{17}$, so $x-2^k$ is a multiple of $17$, so there is no prime $p$ such that $x=2^k+p$.
By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is an infinite arithmetic progression of odd numbers $x$ satisfying all six of the given congruences, hence, not of the form $2^k+p$, $p$ prime.
Odd numbers not of form $p + 2^k$ are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A006285 along with many links to the literature.
The Erdős paper is On integers of the form $2^k+p$ and some related problems, Summa Brasiliensis Mathematicae 2 (1950) 113-123, available at https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1950-07.pdf.
Now, here's why I'm not certain that this qualifies. I don't know when Romanoff asked whether there were infinitely many odd numbers not of the form $2^k+p$. I haven't actually read the 1934 paper, so I don't know whether the question is there. Erdős doesn't cite the 1934 paper for the question; he just writes, "personal communication". So, it's possible that fewer than ten years passed between the publication of the question, and the solution by Erdős.

Incidentally, this paper of Erdös gave rise to the concept of "covering congruences", a fruitful field of research ever since.

The question, raised by Euler, of whether there exists a pair of orthogonal latin squares of order $n$ for some $n\equiv2\bmod4$, was settled (in the affirmative) considerably more than ten years later, by Bose and Shrikhande, in the case $n=22$. Parker then found an example for $n=10$, which I guess counts as a ten-line proof. A picture is at https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Scientific_American_November_1959_Graeco_Latin_square.svg

Could you explain how to understand the picture?

Note that there are three different pictures, and it changes from one to another when you move the cursor. The one where each square contains an upper case Roman letter and a lower case Greek letter, it's done so that each of the ten different Roman letters appears exactly once in each row and in each column, and similarly for the ten different Greek letters, and each pairing of a given Greek with a given Roman letter appears exactly once in the square. The picture with colors, I think the idea is there are ten different colors, (continued next comment)

@LSp, (continued from previous comment) and each square is divided into an upper-left half and a lower-right half, and each color appears once in each of the two positions in each row and also in each columns, and every combination appears in exactly one square. Here's $n=3$: $$\pmatrix{A\alpha&B\beta&C\gamma\cr B\gamma&C\alpha&A\beta\cr C\beta&A\gamma&B\alpha\cr}$$

Thanks!  And some more characters.

Lomonosov's theorem that a bounded operator on a complex (infinite-dimensional) Banach space that commutes with a nontrivial compact operator has a nontrivial invariant subspace had a surprisingly simple proof.
Incidentally, a very similar question was asked on hsm.stackexchange.com some time ago: Is there any example of a long-standing mathematical conjecture whose resolution did not require advanced knowledge? There are many good answers there which I will not repeat here.

Problems like "Is this number (which is not congruent to 4 or 5 mod 9) the sum of 3 cubes of integers?" have a short answer (if the answer is yes) but it is very hard to find the answer.

This was given also as one of the answers here - with some examples: Can you give an example of a complex math problem that is easy to solve?
(Posted by Keith Conrad.)

Similarly, any $\Sigma_1$ arithmetical statement that is true can be easily proven to be true.

\begin{align}
\textbf{Q: } & \text{ What is the prime factorization of } 2^{67}-1\text{?} \\[4pt]
\textbf{A: } & ~193{,}707{,}721 \times 761{,}838{,}257{,}287.
\end{align}
Everybody knows that Frank Nelson Cole did this by hand. (Except those who don't.)
